# Will this for-in loop detection snippet generate unwanted false positives?

Tags: javascript, loops

We all know that [for-in-loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) on arrays are [absolutely evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays). Still, they are often used and the caused errors are complicated to trace down, especially when happening browser-dependent for example because of `indexOf`-shims or such.

So, I have coded this simple snippet which adds an enumerable getter for a "`error`" property on `Array.prototype` (not for use in production code):

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "error", {
    enumerable: true,
    get: function() {
        if (this === Array.prototype) // that looks OK
            return undefined;
        if (window.confirm("Somebody who coded the site you're viewing runs through an Array with a for-in-loop.\nShame on him!\n\nDo you want to raise an Error to trace the origin?"))
            throw new SyntaxError("Array traverse with for-in-loop, touching Array.prototype's 'error' property :-)");
    }
});
```

You can add it as a greasemonkey script for all domains, and you will see alerts on nearly every site :-) Most of them are caused by calls to `jQuery.extend` with questionable arguments, btw.

My question is now: **Are there any situations that legitimate such "wrong" loops**, or **anything else causing false-positive alerts?**

I am wondering how this would affect the usefulness of my code.

Comment: I edited your question to make it less subjective. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Thanks, I like that version - I had no clue what to use as title :-)

Comment: I don't get it, how do you extend this to `Array.prototype`? You'd need to use `__lookupGetter__` or something. It will now simply cause an error because the extend function will get it and the error is thrown and stopping the copying. http://jsfiddle.net/MvgJC/

Comment: Not if you'd use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o).each(function(n){Object.defineProperty(e,n,Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o,n));})` as the extend function instead of jQuery's one (that's why I had written `Object.extend`)...

Answer (score -1):

Yes.  Legitimacy can often be subjective, but...

As an example, perhaps I have a sparse array, where I have only set values at the indexes with data:

```
var a = [];
a[123123] = "foo";
a[1233123] = "bar";
```

If I wanted to iterate over the elements that I defined in this array, then I would use the `for...in` construct.  Even if I coded it defensively, your script would still trigger (a false positive)...

```
for (var prop in a) {
  if (a.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    // this is a legitimate array element
  }
}
```

See also [Why is using "for...in" with array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays) for more information and opinions.

Comment: No, the defensively coded loop (which is fine) will never access `a[prop]` where `prop` is `"error"`, so it's not raising the exception.